# No default active tag on Framewrok7

Tags: html-framework-7

I am developing an app with `PhoneGap` and `Framework7`.
My first screen has a few Tabs like this example:
http://framework7.io/kitchen-sink-material/

[image]

The thing is that always the first Tab is underline by the tag selector, I would like to remove the tag selector(small line under the tab name) , so the first time that the screen has been loaded no under line should be showed, after the user click on the tap will be showed.

This is my code, but by default, I guess, always the first tab is underlined

```
                        <a href="#tab-1" class="tab-link" >
                            <img src="../img/icon_tab_a_off.png" alt="Fincas" width="25" height="24" />
                            <span class="tabbar-label">A</span>
                        </a>


                        <a href="#tab-2" class="tab-link" >     
                            <img src="../img/icon_tab_B_off.png" alt="Cultivos" width="25" height="24" />
                            <span class="tabbar-label">B</span>
                        </a>


                        <a href="#tab-3" class="tab-link">
                            <img src="../img/icon_tab_c_off.png" alt="Actuaciones" width="25" height="24" />
                            <span class="tabbar-label ">C</span>
                        </a>

                        <a href="#tab-4" class="tab-link">
                            <img src="../img/icon_tab_D_off.png" alt="Almacenes" width="25" height="24" />
                            <span class="tabbar-label ">D</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#tab-5" class="tab-link" >
                            <img src="../img/icon_tab_D_off.png" alt="Maquinarias" width="25" height="24" />
                            <span class="tabbar-label ">D</span>
                        </a>

                        <span class="tab-link-highlight" style="width: 70px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></span>

                    </div>
```

Anyone has an idea about how to remove the underline?

Answer (score -1):

I have create one `css` class and 
onshow event of tab calling the function to addClass to tabs and toRemove the class.
You can tried with this

```
.borderGraySolid{
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 0 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #778899;
}
```

Comment: could you please describe the function adding the css-class to the tabs